# /questions/unanswered and /tags allow id parameter, but it does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

The /questions/unanswered and /tags queries both document (as required) and allow an "id" parameter. You can use it as /questions/unanswered?id=1;2;3, but it does nothing (that I can tell) and doesn't make much sense with the queries anyway (to me). Is this going to do something or should it not be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer the case.